# How to store data of different type in C?

Tags: c, polymorphism, virtual-functions, c11

I want to store some data, that can be of a different type that is only known in runtime. I do not want to waste any memory and I want to read all data as float values. In C++ I would have done something like this

```
struct IA {
  virtual float value(int index) = 0;
};

template<class T>
struct A : public IA {
  A(T* bytes, uint32_t size) { 
    values.resize(size);
    memcpy(values.data(), bytes, size*sizeof(T));
  }
  float value(int index) override {
      return static_cast<float>(values[index]);
  }
  std::vector<T> values;
};


int main() {
  uint16_t bytes[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
  IA *a = new A<uint16_t>(bytes, 5);
  float value = a->value(0);
  delete a;
}
```

My question is how this would be done using C instead of C++. I could store the data in an `uint8_t` array and store nr of bits and a `signed` value. Then use a switch case and a cast every time I read a value from the array. But that would be expensive if the array is large and if there are many reads.

I also want to be able to pass the array around without having to do any special if cases?

Comment: You create a separate function for each case. `read_as_uint16_t()` `read_as_uint32_t()` `read_as_uint64_t()` etc. Using `int` or `uint32_t` for indexing arrays is strange, use `size_t`.

Comment: In C++, `A(T* bytes, uint32_t size) : values(bytes, bytes + size){}` would be better than `memcpy`.

Comment: Your code leaks memory. The `a` is never freed.

Comment: Would an union not work?

Comment: When you say different types, do you mean different types of numerical values?  (8 bit int, 16 bit int, 32 bit int, etc.?)

Comment: @ttemple yes exactly

Comment: Does `delete a;` in the code leak `A::values` ? The `A::~A()` function seems never be called. Your code leaks memory. You should make destructor virtual if you want to call interfaces destructor on delete.

Comment: This kind of meta programming is pretty pointless, because there are just so many types that can be converted into a `float`. Namely all the float and integer types. And if it was a floating point type, you wouldn't need any of the overhead code. So the solution you are looking for seems to be how to declare an integer array with a size known in run time. `malloc`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can mimic virtual method with function pointer:

```
typedef struct
{
    void* userData;
    float (*value)(void*, int);
} IA;

float get_float_from_uint16(void* userData, int index)
{
    return ((uint16_t*) userData)[index];
}

int main()
{
    uint16_t bytes[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
    IA a = {bytes, &get_float_from_uint16};

    int index = 0;
    float f = a.value(a.userData, index);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/sWrYds)

Comment: This solution is really nice, there is only one problem with it, the same problem as in c++ I would guess. If the array is large, there will be many function calls that cost a lot?

Comment: @Samantha The first parameter of the function pointed to by struct member `value` is a pointer, so the size of the array will have no impact on performance / memory usage at the time of calling the function pointer.

Comment: yeah, but if you do many lookups, there will always be a function call?

Comment: Neat solution! Just to nitpick, isn't the `&` redundant in `IA a{bytes, &get_float_from_uint16};`?

Comment: @Samantha - Try it out.  Unless you choose to put all of this sequentially, in an in-line form within the main function, there will always be function calls.  Whether or not the function calls are costly in terms of time/memory depends on what they do.  Relatively speaking, calls to this construct will not be costly in terms of time or memory. (as already pointed out by Jim.)   It passes a pointer and there is no heap memory creation or freeing, there are no file writes or reads.

Comment: `IA a{bytes, &get_float_from_uint16};` should be `IA a = {bytes, &get_float_from_uint16};` for a clean compile.  ( And in answer to the comment by @th33lf , the `&` is not needed in this statement: `IA a{bytes, &get_float_from_uint16};`, but does not hurt either. )

Comment: @ryyker: typo fixed and demo added. (used to code in C++).

Comment: @Samantha of course, technically all of this is not required. If you're worried about function calls, `float value = bytes[index];` is all you need. All the code in your example is unnecessary. I hope that you're using float and int here for representative purposes only and you're actually dealing with incompatible types.

Comment: @th33lf: `IA a = {bytes, get_float_from_uint16}` would be enough, but I prefer to be explicit. I might even have used `&bytes[0]` :-).

Comment: If you want type erase the underlying type, there is a cost, `float f = bytes[index];` would have no extra cost, but you don't have the abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's plain and easy (spoiler alert: no, it's not easy, it's very hard). The following code I believe does the same as C++, but is written in C like.

So what happens:

- At first I define `struct IA_s` that is an interface for accessing IA like objects. The structure holds only a virtual table for accessing the objects. The `AI` object has one accessor `IA_value` that does the same as `IA::value` in your code. I also added the objects destructor to the virtual table and `IA_fini` function that is a destructor. It's missing in your code and your code leaks memory.
- Then I create two big macros `A_C` and `A_H`. `A_H` is intented to be used in header files. `A_C` is intended to be used inside sources files. They define a generic implementation of `A` object for any type. The first macro argument is the prefix to be used to prefix all exported symbols. The second is the type. The `A` object holds a dynamic array of some type elements.
- Then I instantiate the generic macros on `uint16_t` type with `uint16_` prefix.
- Then in main function I allocate memory for `A` object, call it's constructor, cast it to `IA` object, get the value for the 2nd index and call all destructors.

Notes:

- constructors are named `*_init`, destructors are named `*_fini`, all functions that touch an object are named `object_*`.
- that was fun to do
- I think I would never use such code in production
- All heaps freed in valgrind

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* IA object ---------------------------------------------- */

// forward definition for IA__vtable_s
struct IA_s;

// the virtual table of the object
struct IA__vtable_s {
    float (*value)(struct IA_s *ctx, size_t index);
    void (*fini)(struct IA_s *ctx);
};

// The structure, holds only the vtable
struct IA_s {
    const struct IA__vtable_s *vtable;
};

/**
 * Get the value holded in index index
 * @param t
 * @return the value
 */
float IA_value(struct IA_s *t, size_t index) {
    assert(t != NULL);
    assert(t->vtable != NULL);
    assert(t->vtable->value != NULL);
    return t->vtable->value(t, index);
}

/**
 * Call the destructor of IA object
 */
void IA_fini(struct IA_s *t) {
    assert(t != NULL);
    assert(t->vtable != NULL);
    assert(t->vtable->fini != NULL);
    t->vtable->fini(t);
}

/* A object ---------------------------------------------- */

/**
 * Header template of A object
 */
#define A_H(NAME, TYPE)  \
/* A object */ \
struct NAME##A_s { \
\
   /* pointer to allocated array */ \
   TYPE *arr; \
\
   /* elements in the array. */ \
   size_t cnt; \
\
   /* I think we have to have that. */ \
   struct IA_s ia; \
\
}; \
\
/* Initializes A object. The *bytes are copied into the object */ \
/* @param t */ \
/* @patam bytes pointer to size count of objects */ \
/* @param size */ \
/* @returns negative errno value on error, 0 on success */ \
int NAME##A_init(struct NAME##A_s *t, TYPE *bytes, size_t size); \
\
/* Deinitializes A object. */ \
void NAME##A_fini(struct NAME##A_s *t); \
\
/* Converts A object in IA object */ \
struct IA_s *NAME##A_to_IA(struct NAME##A_s *t);
// end of A_H

#define A_C(NAME, TYPE) \
\
/* A to IA interface ----------------------------------------------------- */ \
\
/* Convert pointer to IA_s to pointer to A_s */ \
static \
struct NAME##A_s *NAME##A__pnt_from_ia(struct IA_s *t) { \
    return (void*)( ((unsigned char*)(void *)t) - offsetof(struct NAME##A_s, ia) ); \
} \
\
/* this is our value function inside IA interface */ \
static \
float NAME##A__IA_value(struct IA_s *ia, size_t index) { \
    struct NAME##A_s *t = NAME##A__pnt_from_ia(ia); \
    assert(t != NULL); \
    /* UB happens, as in case of vector::operator[] */ \
    assert(index <= t->cnt); \
    return t->arr[index]; \
} \
\
/* this is our destructor inside IA interface */ \
static \
void NAME##A__IA_fini(struct IA_s *ia) { \
    struct NAME##A_s *t = NAME##A__pnt_from_ia(ia); \
    assert(t != NULL); \
    NAME##A_fini(t); \
} \
\
static const struct IA__vtable_s NAME##A__IA_vtable = { \
    .value = NAME##A__IA_value, \
    .fini = NAME##A__IA_fini, \
}; \
\
int NAME##A_init(struct NAME##A_s *t, TYPE *bytes, size_t cnt) { \
    assert(t != NULL); \
    assert(bytes != NULL); \
    if (cnt == 0) {  \
       /* malloc(0) happens to be nonportable */ \
       t->arr = NULL; \
       t->cnt = 0; \
       return 0; \
    } \
    if (SIZE_MAX / sizeof(*t->arr) < cnt) { \
    /* multiplication overflow */ \
    return -EOVERFLOW; \
    } \
    t->arr = malloc(cnt * sizeof(*t->arr)); \
    if (t->arr == NULL) { \
        return -ENOMEM; \
    } \
    t->cnt = cnt; \
    memcpy(t->arr, bytes, cnt * sizeof(*t->arr)); \
    t->ia.vtable = &NAME##A__IA_vtable; \
    return 0; \
} \
void NAME##A_fini(struct NAME##A_s *t) { \
    assert(t != NULL); \
    free(t->arr); \
    t->arr = NULL; \
    t->cnt = 0; \
} \
struct IA_s *NAME##A_to_IA(struct NAME##A_s *t) { \
     assert(t != NULL); \
     return &t->ia; \
}

// A<uint16_t>
A_H(uint16_, uint16_t)
A_C(uint16_, uint16_t)

int main() {
    uint16_t bytes[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // new()
    struct uint16_A_s *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        // destructors
        abort();
    }

    // A::A(bytes, 5)
    int ret = uint16_A_init(temp, bytes, 5);
    if (ret != 0) {
        // destructors
        free(temp);
        abort();
    }

    // IA *ia = A;
    struct IA_s *ia = uint16_A_to_IA(temp);
    if (ia == NULL) {
        // destructors
        uint16_A_fini(temp);
        free(temp);
        abort();
    }

    // finally call IA::value(2)
    float value = IA_value(ia, 2);
    printf("%f\n", value);

    // destructors
    IA_fini(ia); // or uint16_A_fini(temp) depending on which you call delete on

    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: The testers will love you.... haha ;)

Comment: Somebody likes macros.